# Store data from dynamic input form to object (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I has a list of object stored in the state. I want to store input data into the object in a format like this.

```
{
    "parameter" : [{
        "id":"parameter1",
        "value":"value1"
    }, {
        "id":"parameter2", 
        "value":"value2"
    }]
}
```

The thing is the number of input is not constant. If there are 10 inputs, my object length should be 10.

(1) type "value1" in a input id=parameter1

```
{
    "parameter" : [{
        "id":"parameter1",
        "value":"value1"
    }]
}
```

(2) type "value2" in a input id=parameter2

```
{
    "parameter" : [{
        "id":"parameter1",
        "value":"value1"
    }, {
        "id":"parameter2", 
        "value":"value2"
    }]
}
```

(3) type "value3" in a input id=parameter1

```
{
    "parameter" : [{
        "id":"parameter1",
        "value":"value3"
    }, {
        "id":"parameter2", 
        "value":"value2"
    }]
}
```

I wrote onchange handler function but the length of the object always equal to 1. It changed id and value of my object only.

```
onChangeHandlerParameter = e => {
  this.setState({ parameter:[{"id": e.target.id,"value": e.target.value}]})
}
```

(1) type "value1" in a input id=parameter1

```
{
    "parameter" : [{
        "id":"parameter1",
        "value":"value1"
    }]
}
```

(2) type "value2" in a input id=parameter2

```
{
    "parameter" : [{
        "id":"parameter2",
        "value":"value2"
    }]
}
```

Comment: You have to modify the array stored in `parameter`. At the moment you're overwriting the existing array with a new one.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with on change handler

```
onChangeHandlerParameter = e => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
          parameter:[
                    ...prevState.parameter,
                    {"id": e.target.id,"value": e.target.value}
                    ]
               });
}
```

You are changing your state but overwriting the existing one. so you are getting only one item in the array every time that also the latest you added.

'...' is spreader operator and it is spreading of array in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, code you wrote above doesn't work. System warned me that parameter is unused label. I edited the code but it still doesn't work. It showed "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"
[Code]
onChangeHandlerParameter(e){
    this.setState({ parameter:[...this.prevState.parameter,{"id": e.target.id,"value": e.target.value}]})}

Comment: and that error Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" is totally because your function  is not bind with 'this' in the constructor

Comment: define your state with parameter then warning might go

Comment: "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" error is fixed. But when I type 'asd' in input box id='url', it always produce two elements in a array. https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqLqg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You should add the item (push) to the `parameter` array, the current code is just put new values to the whole array.

Could be changed to something like this:

```
onChangeHandlerParameter = e => {
   const { parameter } = this.state;
   parameter.push({"id": e.target.id,"value": e.target.value})
   this.setState({ parameter })
}
```

Comment: this wrong way of doing. you are mutating the state

Comment: de-structured element is referenced element. so when you are manipulating parameter it will directly affect the state.

Comment: State should never be edited directly, always use an immutable way, make use of spread operstor {...this.state}

Answer (score 0):

When you write this way

```
onChangeHandlerParameter = e => {
  this.setState({ parameter:[{"id": e.target.id,"value": e.target.value}]})
}
```

you are actually overwriting the existing state, this will not work, it will always have your last input entered data.

To make this work you need to tweak this a little bit using spread operator.

**Fix:**

```
    onChangeHandlerParameter = e => {
    const currentState = {...this.state};
    const edittedParametersList = [...currentState.parameter];
    let element = {};
    element.id = e.target.id;
    element.value = e.target.value;
    edittedParametersList.parameter.push(element);
    this.setState(edittedParametersList);
  }
```

This way your code will work and also we are making sure we don't mutate state directly **( Which is a best practice )**, we are editing it in an immutable fashion.

happy hacking!

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, the system showed error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined). I defined this.state={parameter=[]} in the constructor. I'm not sure is it relate to this error.